# Serial port communication Arduino VC++

Tags: visual-c++, arduino, serial-port

I am not able to write a string on to my Arduino using [Visual C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B#32-bit_versions). I am somehow able to open the COM port but not able to send data to the Arduino. What would the problem actually be in my case?

```
int main()
{
    HANDLE hComm;
    hComm = CreateFileA("\\\\.\\COM11",
            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
            0,
            0,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
            0);

    if (hComm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("com not opened");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("COM OPENED");
    }

    COMMTIMEOUTS cto = { 1, 100, 1000, 0, 0 };
    DCB dcb;
    memset(&dcb,0,sizeof(dcb));
    dcb.DCBlength = sizeof(dcb);
    dcb.BaudRate = 38400;
    dcb.fBinary = 1;
    dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;
    dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    dcb.ByteSize = 8;

    if(!SetCommState(hComm,&dcb))
    {
        printf("HI");
    }

    while(1)
    {
        char bag[]="L";
        DWORD read=0 ;
        DWORD write=1; // Number of bytes to write to serial port
        //         Decmial value to write to serial port
        WriteFile(hComm, bag,write,&write, NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know you "cannot send data "? What are your results? A great way to test serial comms is to use a virtual serial port like com0com.

Comment: Please take more care in formatting code in your questions. As it was the code you posted was almost unreadable and would have made anyone who choose to help you work much harder than they should have.

Comment: thats because i programmed arduino to brink a light if "L" is sent and i tried using tera term and light blinks when i send "L" through tera term software

Answer (score 2):

You have to set **every** member of the `DCB` structure correctly.  The easiest thing to do is to read the existing settings with [`GetCommState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363260.aspx), then change just the ones you care about.

Right now your flow control is most likely wrong.

Oh, you also initialized a timeout structure, but never applied those settings to the port.

Comment: i have applied the timeout structure but still not able to see it working.

Comment: the code which is given in the website http://webhole.net/2010/05/01/arduino-visual-c-plus-plus-tutorial/  is working but can i use it with my win32 console application.  the code works well as a clr application.