# Serial Port Commands

Tags: serial-port, command, c++-cli

I need to send commands through Serial Port to control a electronic device. According the datasheet of this device, the command structure is as follows:  Prefix Command Carriage Return. There are some commands, e.g. GOCW_BY1, STATUSRQ, etc. 
The program will be developed in C++/CLI. After, I create the SerialPort objectand I set the port parameters, I send commands using the write("String") method of SerialPort class. However, I haven't still realized what kind of string I must set on write method.
Moreover, I don't know the meaning of prefix. Could you help me?

Comment: The prefix will be found in the device datasheet.

Answer (score 0):

In C++/CLI, I recommend against using the .NET `System::IO::Ports::SerialPort` class.  C++/CLI gives you convenient access to the Win32 API, which are far more powerful (and IMO easier to use) than the .NET API.

See for example [this question about accessing serial ports from C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9351470/103167)